# "autocmd!" on a separate line vs. "autocmd! <the autocmd itself>"

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

From what I have read in a book by Steve Losh ([chapter 14](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html)), it seems that to avoid performance issues, it is best practise to enclose autocommands, even the single ones, in autocommand groups:

```
augroup testgroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWrite * :echom "Cats"
augroup END
```

I've just started to learn Vim and my question is quite simple. Is it the same as using

```
augroup testgroup
  autocmd! BufWrite * :echom "Cats"
augroup END
```

?

I ask this because Steve hasn't provided this second version in his book (at least in the 14 chapter), though it looks more concise.

Comment: Probably `:help autocmd-remove` can clarify the difference, or press `K` in a vim file over `autocmd` and scroll down. (Answer: for a single autocmd, there is no difference; however, it is liable to be confusing _esp._ with multiple autocommands where you want to use no `!` on the subsequent ones.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks a lot, I have just read it. One more small question: Is it correct that using augroups here is in fact optional? Isn't it that I can simply use `autocmd! BufWrite * :echom "Cats"` without enclosing it in an augroup and this will be enough to avoid performace issues?

Comment: @james, about your "small question," it's not the same. For example, if you use two `autocmd!` for the same `BufWrite *` event-pattern pair, the second one would delete the first one. Whereas if you wrapped these two in an augroup,  a single `au!` at the start of the augroup would delete all autocmds in that augroup before re-defining them. So both the autocmds for that event-pattern pair will be registered.

Comment: @kadekai worse: without a group, `autocmd!` deletes all the commands in the default group (see my answer below and `:help autocmd-groups`). Really, just use `autocmd!` once at the top of the group and don't confuse anyone :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yeah, now that I see it, I was trying to explain exactly what you wrote in your answer. I just didn't see it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in `:help autocmd-remove`:

```
:au[tocmd]! [group] {event} {aupat} [++once] [++nested] {cmd}
            Remove all autocommands associated with {event} and
            {aupat}, and add the command {cmd}.
            See |autocmd-once| for [++once].
            See |autocmd-nested| for [++nested].

[…]

When the [group] argument is not given, Vim uses the current group (as defined
with ":augroup"); otherwise, Vim uses the group defined with [group].
```

For a single autocmd ***in a group***, there is (almost<sup>1</sup>) no difference It is liable to be confusing, especially with multiple autocommands—you likely do not want `!` on the subsequent ones.

Note the qualifer: `autocmd!` outside of a group removes all autocommands in the default group (so `autocmd! BufWrite * :echom "Cats"` would remove all ungrouped `BufWrite *` autocommands and add the single autocommand `:echom "Cats"`).

---

1. @filbranden points out below that there is a large difference if you modify the code:

> For example, if you update the vimscript file to change the `autocmd` from `BufWrite` to `BufWritePost` and reload it, […] the bare `autocmd!` will erase the `BufWrite` and keep only the `BufWritePost`, while […] the `autocmd!` for the specific event/command will keep both the `BufWrite` and `BufWritePost` [since it will delete only the matching `BufWritePost`].

Comment: There's actually a difference for a single autocmd in a group. For example, if you update the vimscript file to change the autocmd from BufWrite to BufWritePost and reload it, the first one (with the bare `autocmd!`) will erase the BufWrite and keep only the BufWritePost, while the second one (with the `autocmd!` for the specific event/command) will keep both the BufWrite and BufWritePost. Right? You go into details of removing all auto-commands in a group, but maybe best to make it explicit of the case where you're updating the vimscript.

Comment: @filbranden great point that I hadn't considered.